# Как сделать ,чтобы при обновлении страницы не выводилась "повторная отправка формы" и ранее добавленный комментарий не добавлялся снова

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
<?php include "header.php" ?>
<?php require "config.php" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/config/styleart.css">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Статья</title>
  <style>
      @font-face {
        font-family:Pacifico-Regular;
        src: url(/fonts/pacificoregular.ttf);
    }
    @font-face {
       font-family:spectraisc-lightItalic;
       src: url(/fonts/spectraisc-lightItalic.ttf);
    }
  </style>
 </head>
<body>
<h1 id="title"><?php $articles = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `id` = " . (int) $_GET['id']); 
if( mysqli_num_rows($articles) <= 0  )
{
?></h1>


<div class="container">
<h1 id="title">Статья не найдена</h1>
<p id="text">Запрашиваемая вами статья не существует</p>
    </div>
 <?php
}
else
{
$art = mysqli_fetch_assoc($articles);
mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE `articles` SET `views` = `views` + 1 WHERE `id` = ". (int) $art['id'])
?></h1>
  <div class="container">
  <h1 id="title"><?php echo $art['title']; ?></h1>
  <p id="prosmotri"><?php echo $art['views'];?>просмотров</p>
  <p id="text"><?php echo $art['text']; ?></p>
      </div>
<div class="container2">
<h1 id="mediatext">Материалы к статье</h1>
<p class="url">Ссылки <br>
<a href="#">1</a>
<a href="#">1</a>
<a href="#">1</a>
</p>
<div class="container3">
<p class="photo">Фото <br>
<img src="../static/images/<?php echo $art['image']; ?>" style="max-width: 100%;">
</div>
<?php 

?>
<?php 
$comments = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `arcticles_id` = ". (int) $art['id']. " ORDER BY `id` DESC ");
if( mysqli_num_rows( $comments ) <= 0 ) 
{
?> <p id="nokoments">Нет коментариев!!!!</p><?php;
} 
while( $comment = mysqli_fetch_assoc($comments) )
{
?> 
<div class="container_koment">
<h1 id="zagcoment">Коментарий</h1>
<p id="date"><?php echo $comment['pupdate'];?></p>
<p id="autor_comment"><?php echo mb_substr(strip_tags($comment['autor_comment']),0,50,'utf-8')?></p>
<p id="text_comment"><?php echo mb_substr(strip_tags($comment['text']),0,120,'utf-8')?></p>
</div>
<?php
} 
?>
<br>
<div id="yakor" class="container4">
<?php
if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'send')) {
    $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
    $text = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'text');
    if (!$name or !$text) {
     echo '<h1 id="error_comment">Вы не ввели все данные!!!</h1>';
    } else {
      $add_comment = mysqli_query($connection," INSERT INTO `comments` (`id`, `autor_comment`, `text`, `pupdate`, `arcticles_id`) VALUES (NULL, '".$name."', '".$text."', current_timestamp(),'".$art['id']."')");
    }
}
?>
<form method="post" >
        <h1 id="zag_comment_add">Добавить свой комментарий</h1>
        <input  id="komentname" name="name" placeholder="Введите имя(до 50 символов)">
        <input name="text" id="text_comment" placeholder="Напишите свой комментарий(до 120символов)">
        <button  id="otp" name="send" href="#otp">Отправить</button>
</form>

</div>
</div>
<?php
} 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Если делать на php, то разделить страницы на добавление и просмотр... Либо делать редирект на данную страницу.

Comment: Ну и как вариант использовать js

Comment: а какой js скрипт?

Comment: файл обработчик php запроса для добавления комментариев и вывода всех комментариев. js будет отсылать новый комментарий в базу данных и обновлять список всех.

Answer (score 0):

Для обработки подойдёт и

```
$url = 'http' . ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') ? 's' : '') . '://';
$url = $url . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header("Location: {$url}");
```

Comment: Спасибо,а его кидать  в   тег form?